# How to get json from CSV file?

Tags: javascript, python, pandas

I have a CSV file that contains countries' names and their city's names like the following.

> Input

```
Kabul                   Afghanistan
Kandahar                Afghanistan
Herat                   Afghanistan
Tirana                  Albania
Algiers                 Algeria
Luanda                  Angola
Huambo                  Angola
Cabinda                 Angola
Benguela                Angola
Lobito                  Angola
Buenos Aires            Argentina
Cordoba                 Argentina
Rosario                 Argentina
San Miguel de Tucuman   Argentina
...                     ...
```

I want to get a JSON file from this data by using any language or any library. I heard that it can be achieved by pandas of Python or JavaScript. (There are almost 2600 cities.)

> Output

```
cities = {
    "Afghanistan": ["Kabul", "Kandahar", "Herat"],
    "Albania"    : ["Tirana", "Algiers"],
    "Angola"     : ["Luanda", "Huambo", "Cabinda", "Benguela", "Lobito"],
    "Argentina"  : ["Buenos Aires", "Cordoba", "Rosario", "San Marino de Tucuman"],
    ...            ...
}
```

How can I get this?

I tried with [pandas](https://www.shanelynn.ie/python-pandas-read-csv-load-data-from-csv-files/) but I have no idea how to continue as I am a newbie on Python. Is there any way?

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

Comment: This seems like a simple loop that reads each line of the CSV, splits it into city and country, then either creates or appends to the dictionary entry for that country.

Comment: If you use pandas you should be able to use its `.groupby()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pandas` and `groupby`

I uses `io` only to create minimal working example but you should use filename.

```
text = '''Kabul                   Afghanistan
Kandahar                Afghanistan
Herat                   Afghanistan
Tirana                  Albania
Algiers                 Algeria
Luanda                  Angola
Huambo                  Angola
Cabinda                 Angola
Benguela                Angola
Lobito                  Angola
Buenos Aires            Argentina
Cordoba                 Argentina
Rosario                 Argentina
San Miguel de Tucuman   Argentina'''

import pandas as pd
import io

#fh = "filename.csv"
#df = pd.read_csv(fh, sep='\s{2,}', names=['city', 'country'])

fh = io.StringIO(text)
df = pd.read_csv(fh, sep='\s{2,}', names=['city', 'country'])

cities = {}

for country, group in df.groupby('country'):
    cities[country] = group['city'].to_list()

print(cities)
```

And without `pandas` but using normal `open()` and `read()`.

Because names are separated by few spaces so I use `regex`. I couldn't do it with standard module `csv` because it expects single char as separator.

```
text = '''Kabul                   Afghanistan
Kandahar                Afghanistan
Herat                   Afghanistan
Tirana                  Albania
Algiers                 Algeria
Luanda                  Angola
Huambo                  Angola
Cabinda                 Angola
Benguela                Angola
Lobito                  Angola
Buenos Aires            Argentina
Cordoba                 Argentina
Rosario                 Argentina
San Miguel de Tucuman   Argentina'''

import re
import io

#fh = open('filename.csv')

fh = io.StringIO(text)
 
cities = {}

for line in fh:
    line = line.strip()
    city, country  = re.split(' {2,}', line)
    if country not in cities:
        cities[country] = []

    cities[country].append(city)

print(cities)
```

---

**EDIT:**

If you need it as JSON data

```
import json

data = json.dumps(cities)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The first example works perfectly. In the second example, country and city position was changed like this.`cities=['Kabul': 'Afghanistan', 'Kandahar': 'Afghanistan']`  Anyway all works well as I expected. :)

Comment: now I see: it has to be `city, country = ... ` instead of `country, city = ...`

Comment: Can I change all single quotes into double quotes like this?  `cities=['Kabul': 'Afghanistan', 'Kandahar': 'Afghanistan']` into `cities=["Kabul": "Afghanistan", "Kandahar": "Afghanistan"]`

Comment: quotes are not imporant for JSON data. If you want to display it with different quotes then you will have to write code to display every element separatelly and format it. OR you would have to convert all to string and `replace` quotes. But as I said quotes are not important for JSON data. And if you want to send it as JSON data then use `json.dumps(cities)` and it will create correct JSON data with correct quotes.

Comment: "quotes are not important for JSON data" --- @furas did you mean quotes aren't important on the python side? I believe only double quotes are allowed for valid JSON.

Comment: @merced yes, quotes are not important on Python side. You have `json.dumps(cities)` to create JSON with expected quotes. I expect that OP tried to convert Python data to JSON string manually.

Comment: @furas 's answer was correct. I got correct `JSON data from `CSV` based on his answer. Fortunately, python handles the quote of `JSON` by itself. Following is the result that I got from his answer.  `cities = {'Afghanistan': ['Kabul', 'Kandahar'], 'Saudi Arabia': ["Ha'il", "At Ta'if", 'Buraydah'], 'Russia': ["Komsomol'sk-na-Amure", 'Moscow']}`. As you can see if there is a single quote in city name, then python converts it into double quotes automatically.

Answer (score 2):

This may work.
Assuming that each line between cities and countries have a separation of 2 or more lines

```
import fs from "fs";
const fileData = fs.readFileSync("./file.csv");
const convertToJson = (fileData) => {
    const lines = fileData.split(/\n/g) || [];
    const dictionary = {};
    lines.forEach(line => {
        const lineSplit = line.split(/\s{2,}/g);
        if (lineSplit.length == 2 && !dictionary[lineSplit[1]] ) {
            dictionary[lineSplit[1]] = [];
        }
        dictionary[lineSplit[1]].push(lineSplit[0]);
    });
    return dictionary;
}
console.log(convertToJson(fileData.toString()));
```